# Handlebars - nested condition in partial

Tags: html, handlebars.js

Hi my page looks like this:

```
---
title: Coffee
replace: true
---
{{> products-list-style}}
```

and my partial "products-list-style" like:

```
{{#if ../replace}}Replace{{else}}Add to Cart{{/if}}
```

I am new to handlebars, so I am not sure about nesting conditions. I tried ../../ and using "this" word as second parametr in my page, but nothing works. Any help? Is it possible to nest parameter from page into partial?

Comment: What version of handlebars do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the context is being passed down from the parent template to partials, but only the context local to where the partial is being included. And partials are not able to access parent of their context.

A simple example passing the whole parent template context, the properties are accessible directly:

```
var model = {
    title: 'Coffee',
    replace: true
}

handlebars.registerPartial('products-list-style',
    '{{#if replace}}Replace{{else}}Add to Cart{{/if}}')

var template = handlebars.compile(
    '{{title}}, {{replace}}, {{> products-list-style}}')

console.log(template(model))
```

Yields:

```
Coffee, true, Replace
```

An example passing only `item` part of the parent template context using `with` helper:

```
var model = {
    pageTitle: 'My coffee page',
    item: {
        title: 'Coffee',
        replace: true
    }
}

handlebars.registerPartial('products-list-style',
    '{{#if replace}}Replace{{else}}Add to Cart{{/if}}, ' +
    'this: {{.}}, parent: {{..}}, page title: {{../pageTitle}}')

var template = handlebars.compile(
    '{{pageTitle}}\n' +
    '{{#with item}}{{title}}, {{replace}}, {{> products-list-style}}{{/with}}')

console.log(template(model))
```

Yields:

```
My coffee page
Coffee, true, Replace, this: [object Object], parent: , page title:
```

The `item` properties are accessible directly, but the partial cannot access the parent of it's context.

This behavior is the same using both Handlebars 1.3.0 and 2.0.0.